# If I press one key and then another too fast, my pygame sprite stops moving

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame so my code is a bit messy but I hope you can help me. When I make a sprite move it works fine, but if I switch keys really fast, or if I press the jump button and let go, my sprite stops moving.

```
import shelve
import sys, pygame, pygame.mixer
import time
from pygame.locals import *
import random
pygame.init()
shelfFile = shelve.open('save_game')

#screen
sise = width, hight = 700, 600
red = 30,30,30
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(sise)

pygame.display.set_caption('Thing')

#varuables
background = pygame.image.load('background.png')
player = pygame.image.load('you.png')
enemy1 = pygame.image.load('enemy1.png')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
px = shelfFile['px']
py = shelfFile['py']
health = shelfFile['health']
x2 = 0

x = 0
y = 0
u = 0
d = 0
t = 0
r = 0

ex = 0
ey = 0


cutseane = shelfFile ['cutseane']
black = 255,255,255

Punch = False

color = 255,0,0
radius = 5


room = shelfFile['room']

ehealth = shelfFile['ehealth']


while True:
    pygame.event.get()
    if jump == 1:
        y = -20
    if py <= 200:
        jump = 2
    if jump == 2:
        y = +20
    if py >= 480:
        py = 480

                #The Wall
    if px <= 0:
        px = 0
    if px >= 630:
        px = 630
    pygame.display.flip()
    screen.blit(background,(1,1))
    screen.blit(player,(px,py))
    #if ehealth >= 1:
        #screen.blit(enemy1,(ex,ey))
    #else:
        #ex = 0
        #ey = 0
                px = px + x 
    py = py + y
    clock.tick(30)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()



        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            shelfFile['px'] = px
            shelfFile['py'] = py
            shelfFile['health'] = health
            shelfFile['ehealth'] = ehealth
            shelfFile['cutseane'] = cutseane
            shelfFile['room'] = room
            shelfFile.close()
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit();



                    #Player Movement
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if keys [pygame.K_0]:
                health -= 1
                text = 1
                shelfFile['text'] = text
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x = -15
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x = +15
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y = +15
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y = -15
        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and x > 0:
                x = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and x < 0:
                x = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP and x > 0:
                y = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and x < 0:
                y = 0
```

Comment: Please edit your post and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means everything that is not related to the problem should be removed, but we should still be able to run the program and reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event loop is really messed up and should be restructured. `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` shouldn't be called in the event loop, but in the outer while loop. I've got a minimal example to show you one way to do the movement and event handling (only with the event loop and without `key.get_pressed`).

```
import sys
import pygame


pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 600))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = pygame.Surface((30, 30))
player.fill((120, 240, 90))

px = 100
py = 200
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            # If player is on the ground, jump (in more advanced
            # games you need collision detection instead >= 480).
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and py >= 480:
                y_speed = -20
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 10
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_speed = -10
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            # If player is moving right, stop him.
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and x_speed > 0:
                x_speed = 0
            # If player is moving left, stop him.
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and x_speed < 0:
                x_speed = 0

    # Don't jump too high.
    if py <= 200:
        y_speed = 20
    # Don't go below y = 480.
    if py >= 480:
        py = 480

    # Move the player.
    px += x_speed
    py += y_speed
    # The Wall.
    if px <= 0:
        px = 0
    if px >= 630:
        px = 630

    screen.fill((50, 50, 50))
    screen.blit(player, (px, py))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: Never mind i messed up on doing your example i'm doing the movement. and by the way    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()    has to be in the loop

Comment: ok i just used your example code and now i cant stop moving i show you the movement part so you can help me (i changed some things up top Its also not a side scroller any more its a top down)

Comment: You've flipped the `>` greater than sign in this line `if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and x > 0:` and in `elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and x < 0:`. Also, to enable the jumping again you need to change `elif event.key == pygame.K_UP: y = +15` to `elif event.key == pygame.K_UP: jump = 1`, if you want to keep your old jumping code. I just wanted to show you in my example that you actually don't need the `jump` variable, but you can still do it in your way.

Comment: Stack Overflow really isn't the right website for this kind of debugging/tutoring. I recommend to use a forum like [reddit.com/r/pygame](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/) instead. Also, never change your question in such a way that answers are invalidated and don't make sense anymore. You've incorporated some of my suggestions into your answer and other people can't see the original problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that in some places, you wrote `y = +20` instead of `y += 20`. If you want `y` to increase by 20 units, do `y += 20`, if you want `y` to be set to the value 20, do `y = 20` (does the same thing as `y = +20`). I don't know what you are trying to do because I don't have your png files and I can't run the program to see what happens. Also, if it even is an unintentional mistake, you did the same thing for negatives and in other parts of the code.

This isn't really a mistake, it will work if not corrected but you also spelled some things wrong (if it was intentional, ignore this.)

sise should be size,
hight should be height,
cutseane should be cutscene...

There are other mistakes. If all of this works and they are not just typos, then you might be using some version of python that I am not aware of.

Comment: Better remove the paragraph about `black = 255,255,255`, because it actually works. The comma makes the tuple not the parentheses. BTW, @Matt black is `0, 0, 0`. ;P

Comment: Thanks for the help any ways but i want the x = +10  i had it to the playerx later playerx = px